# How can i force next button(the URL) in a survey to use IsDlg=0

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I would like to create a custom aspx page before they start a survey.
So first page would have a button with START.This would link directly to the survey page
with no masterpage and left side menu.
The problem is i notice the the parameter IsDlg=1 is always appended when i click next and this doesn't allow scroll bar.But hen i change it to IsDlg=0 it does.

What ways can i show the survey to users without masterpages and left menu.
I would also like to redirect it to another page when done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery and In jQuery select button with text property. Then you can play around with it. I have done it like that that is the reason I am telling you.

Comment: Thanks Milind.
Can you please elaborate more how i can use jquery to do this?
Looking at the input html NEXT button i can't see any url link.
Any ideas?